# JQUERY load div in page when pressing on button on another div

Tags: jquery, html, reload

OK here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hello!</title>
<style>
#add_data{
display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button id="data">Data</button>
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
    <a href="#" id="add_new_data">Add New Data</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div id="add_data">
    <input type="text" /><br>
    <input type="text" /><br>
    <input type="text" /><br>
    <input type="text" /><br>
    <input type="submit" />
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#add_new_data").click(function(){
    $("#container").fadeOut();
    $("#add_data").fadeIn();
    return false;
});
$("#data").click(function(){
    $("#container").empty().fadeIn().load("test.html" + " #content");
    $("#add_data").fadeOut();
    return false;
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now try to press on Add New Data button , it will fadeout my data and show the form inputs

Now press on Data button to load data and fadeout my form inputs

finally press on Add New Data button , and here is my problem

i want to reload my div when i press on data button but when i do this , i can't use any other buttons

how to fix this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this because you haven't made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) but I think the issue is because your events aren't delegated and so when you replace the element the events are no longer attached.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on("click", "#add_new_data", function(){
        $("#container").fadeOut();
        $("#add_data").fadeIn();
        return false;
    });
    $("body").on("click", "#data", function(){
        $("#container").empty().fadeIn().load("test.html" + " #content");
        $("#add_data").fadeOut();
        return false;
    });
});
```

See: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

As requested, here's **My Attempt to Explain Event Delegation:**

> Imagine you have some elements with a class of '`clickme`'...
>
> ```
> <div class='clickme'>me</div>
> <div class='clickme'>and me</div>
> <div class='clickme'>me too</div>
> ```
>
> ...to which you attach an `event listener` like so:
>
> ```
> $(".clickme").click(function(){alert("click!");});
> ```
>
> ...all good so far? Now you remove/replace these elements:
>
> ```
> $(".clickme").remove();
> $(body).append($("<div class='clickme'>what about me?</div>"));
> ```
>
> When you remove the element the event listeners are also removed (Why
>   listen out for an event on an element that no longer exists?) So
>   although your new element has the right class it *didn't exist at the
>   time the event listeners were applied*.
>
> So how do we apply an event listener to an element that doesnt yet
>   exist? We 'delegate' it to a responsible parent. IE, we give the task
>   to a parent element and say "when I click on you please check if I'm
>   clicking on this particular child of yours". EG:
>
> ```
> $("#parent").on("click", ".clickme", function(){alert("click!");});
> ```
>
> "*Hey `#parent`, when I `click` on you please check if the `event target` has a class of `clickme`. If so, shout up. Ta.*" ;)

Comment: Thank you buddy , it solved my problem , but can you explain it in more details to understand it well :)

Answer (score 0):

Move Add New Data up a line (outside of #content) and use .load on #content instead of #container so that you don't delete #add_new_data